# Add second total row using fnFooterCallback in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatables

I have the following footer table:

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="9">Total amount:</th> 
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="9">Grand total:</th> 
        <th colspan="2"></th>
    </tr>                                    
</tfoot>
```

I am using jQuery DataTable to render the data from mySQL and I am using the first footer row to sumarise values from table in two columns, let's say Amount and SAmount

```
"fnFooterCallback": function ( nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {
    var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
    nCells[0].innerHTML = Amount;

    var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
    nCells[1].innerHTML = SAmount;
});
```

In the second footer row I want to insert the difference between total Amount and SAmount.
How can I insert the difference total row in second footer row?

Comment: I found it by myself
        var secondRow = $(nRow).next()[0];
        var nCells = secondRow.getElementsByTagName('td');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by myself

```
var secondRow = $(nRow).next()[0]; 
var nCells = secondRow.getElementsByTagName('td');
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for information. If you want to add third footer row to the datatable then you can use following:

var thirdRow = $($(nRow).next()[0]).next()[0];
var nCells = thirdRow.getElementsByTagName('th');

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. The OP only asked on how to add a second row. Therefore your answer should have been a comment on the corresponding answer rather than an answer. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export using the plugin it will only export the first row of the footer, to solve this you can modify the function `_fnGetDataTablesData` in `dataTables.tableTools.js`, change the footer part with this new code:

```
if (oConfig.bFooter && dt.nTFoot !== null) {
    aRow = [];
    for (i = 0, iLen = dt.nTFoot.childElementCount; i < iLen; i++) {
        for (j = 0, jLen = dt.nTFoot.children[i].childElementCount; j < jLen; j++) {
            sLoopData = dt.nTFoot.children[i].cells[j].innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, " ").replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
            sLoopData = this._fnHtmlDecode(sLoopData);
            aRow.push(this._fnBoundData(sLoopData, oConfig.sFieldBoundary, regex));
        }
        aData.push(aRow.join(oConfig.sFieldSeperator));
        aRow = [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Ernesto Ramos will throw errors if the table footer has any colspans in it (yes I know datatables doesn't support colspans). Tabletools handles errors by clearing the data, so the file is completely empty.

This solution below is very similar to above, but allows for colspans.

```
if (oConfig.bFooter && dt.nTFoot !== null) {
    var numRows = dt.nTFoot.rows.length;

    for (j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
        aRow = [];
        for (i = 0, iLen = dt.aoColumns.length ; i < iLen ; i++) {
            if (aColumnsInc[i] && dt.nTFoot.rows[j].cells[i] && dt.aoColumns[i].nTf !== null) {
                sLoopData = dt.nTFoot.rows[j].cells[i].innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, " ").replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
                sLoopData = this._fnHtmlDecode(sLoopData);
                aRow.push(this._fnBoundData(sLoopData, oConfig.sFieldBoundary, regex));
            }
        }

        aData.push(aRow.join(oConfig.sFieldSeperator));
    }
}
```